# Resize view with Auto Layout between 3.5 and 4 inch form factor

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, constraints, autolayout

I have a prototype tableview cell, with a custom view inside of the tableview cell. The view controller that contains the tableview will only be displayed in landscape mode. The goal is for the UIView that is inside of the tableview cell to resize it's width based on the form factor. So for example there might be a 20pt spacing on the left and right and then the uiview resizes it's width to fill the rest of the space. I'm hoping to do this with storyboard and autolayout.

In 3.5 inch form factor it looks like this (this is what it should look like in 4 inch mode as well)

[image]

In 4 inch form factor it looks like this (width didn't auto resize)
[image]

I understand that the 'auto layout' here is legal, since the horizontal space is >20 on the 4 inch form factor as well. The heart of the question though is... how do I get a subview to autoresize it's width when the width of the screen changes using storyboard/autolayout/constraints?

Comment: Your horizontal spacing to the sides should be =20 not >=20, then it will be inset by 20 points on any size screen or form factor.

Comment: That does not work. If I set them to be equal to twenty they get messed up as soon as I press the resize form factor button in xcode. For example, if I set them equal to 20 in the 4 inch form factor, and then press the 3.5 inch factor button... The view stays the same size (too wide) and the 20 inch spacer turns into a -68 spacer

Comment: I think that may be a bug in Xcode. I think I remember something about the constraints being added to the cell rather that the cell's content view (which is where it should be). Do you get the same wrong behavior when you test it in the simulator?

Comment: If you do the same thing (20 point spacing to the edges) with a view in a controller's main view, instead of in a table view cell, it works fine. I think I've fixed things like this by adding the view and the constraints to the cell's contentView in code.

Comment: I think you may be right. I'll do some more work in code and let you know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need are following four constraints to autosize your cell view for 3.5 and 4 inches screens.

[image]

Xcode 4.6 `Interface Builder` has a bug where at times it does not properly apply constraints when switching ViewController size between 3.5" and 4" at design time. However, it works just fine when opened in the 3.5" and 4" simulators.